# format rounding the pricision part. why

Tags: python-3.x

what is the difference between the below code, can explain?

print(format(678906.3456789,"10.2f"))
678906.35
print(format(67890611111111111.3456789111111111111111101111111111111111111101,"10.2f"))
67890611111111112.00

> > > print(format(67890611111111111.3456789111111111111111101111111111111111111101,"19.2f"))
> > > 67890611111111112.00
> > > print(format(67890611111111111.3456789111111111111111101111111111111111111101,"<10.2f"))
> > > 67890611111111112.00

Comment: Your input (`67890611111111111.[...]`) has an amount of significant digits that exceeds the limitation of [double precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), so the result is not mathematically correct.

Answer (score 0):

As the first comment has alluded. The number of `significant digits` has exceeded the limits of the `10.2f` (double precission format).

Basically, in very generic terms as a guide, one gets around **15 digits** to play with after which accuracy is lost (ie. the number is too big).

by way of example this separates the `large number` with `_` so that it is clearer.

```py
# this works because the significant figure limit is not exceeded
print(format(678906.3456789,"10.2f"))
# 678906.35

# too many significant figures
print(format(67890611111111111.3456789111111111111111101111111111111111111101,"10.2f"))
# 67890611111111112.00

# still too many significant figures  (but with _ to highlight this)
print(format(67_890_611_111_111_111.34567891111111111,"10.2f"))
# 67890611111111112.00


# if we remove some of the numbers (by 1000 factor), we get to see the decimals again
print(format(67_890_611_111_111.34567891111111111,"10.2f"))
# 67890611111111.34
```

The issues and limitations are set out in the docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: A better rule of thumb is 15 significant digits, how it's specified by [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats), the exact value for decimals digits of **double64** alias **Double precision** is **15.95**.

Comment: @Wolf: comment appreciated. when number of digits gets large, most go to scientfic mode anyway or need to be aware of the floating point.

Comment: Absolutely. I'd think floating point arithmetic should only be used where high precision doesn't matter. That's why humans have invented unit prefixes: only few people really care about precision beyond 7, in most cases 4 digits will be sufficient.

Comment: If you try f'{9999999999999999:16.0f}' in the python console, you'll see an impressive case where python fails on 16 significant decimal digits. So I'd suggest you to fix your **bold** advice.

Comment: i am going blind counting those 9's,  but i have changed it to be on the safe size.